# Record execution time excluding cin

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

I am making a program template that will allow for me to handle multiple test cases, and I would like to record the amount of time it takes to compute each testcase. I want to exclude the time it takes to type input however. I don't really want to fit in the time recording code inside the solve function and place my input code before it, since it seems a bit troublesome and untidy.

Here is an example:

```
void solve(int tc) {
    int n; cin >> n; // I want to start checking the time it takes between here.
    vector<int> a(1000,n);
    cout << accumulate(a.begin(),a.end(),0);
    cout << "\n"; // and here
}

int main() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0);
    int tc; cin >> tc;
    int ogtc = tc;
    while(tc--)
    {
        // what I have already tried  
        #ifdef RON0PC
        auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        #endif
        solve(ogtc-tc);
        #ifdef RON0PC
        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        cout << setprecision(4) << fixed;
        cout << "Execution time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(end - begin).count() << " seconds" << endl;
        #endif
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Refactor your code.  Make a `take_input` function that fills your data set, and then have multiple `do_work` functions for each different algorithm that do the different implementations.  Then you can time how long it takes to do the `do_work` functions.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Maybe I could even just have the input at the very beginning of the while tc-- part and have arguments for the solve function I suppose. Is there any kind of clock that pauses automatically when waiting for cin?

Comment: @rudrrayanmanna _"Is there any kind of clock that pauses automatically when waiting for cin?"_ No. Just start measuring only for what you want to measure.